# How to filter a dfm by documents with at least n terms in quanteda?

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I am analyzing text data from a round table, and I would like to know if it is possible to filter only those documents which have more than "n" terms?

My corpus has documents which contains only 1 word, such as: "Thanks", "Sometimes", "Really", "go". I would like to remove then in order to decrease sparsity.

I tried `dfm_trim` from `quanteda` but I couldn't handle it:

```
corpus_post80inaug <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, Year > 1980)
dfm <- dfm(corpus_post80inaug)
ntoken(dfm)
1981-Reagan  1985-Reagan    1989-Bush 1993-Clinton 1997-Clinton 
       2790         2921         2681         1833         2449 
  2001-Bush    2005-Bush   2009-Obama   2013-Obama   2017-Trump 
       1808         2319         2711         2317         1660 
dfm <- dfm_trim(dfm, min_docfreq = 2000)
ntoken(dfm)
1981-Reagan  1985-Reagan    1989-Bush 1993-Clinton 1997-Clinton 
          0            0            0            0            0 
  2001-Bush    2005-Bush   2009-Obama   2013-Obama   2017-Trump 
          0            0            0            0            0
```

I would expect that only 1993-Clinton, 2001-Bush and 2017-Trump would have 0, or get rid off `dfm`.
Obs.: This example is only for illustration purpose, it is not the text data I am analyzing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `dfm_subset`, not `dfm_trim`. `dfm_trim` calculates frequencies across all documents, not per document. Though you can specify that the minimum (or maximum) documents that the term should appear in. For removing documents, we use `dfm_subset`.

```
corpus_post80inaug <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, Year > 1980)
dfm <- dfm(corpus_post80inaug)

# remove documents with less than 2000 tokens. 
my_dfm <- dfm_subset(dfm, ntoken(dfm) >= 2000)

ntoken(my_dfm)
 1981-Reagan  1985-Reagan    1989-Bush 1997-Clinton    2005-Bush   2009-Obama   2013-Obama 
        2790         2921         2681         2449         2319         2711         2317
```

Comment: A helpful way to think of it: `dfm_trim()` removes features, never documents. `dfm_subset()` removes documents, never features.